# How can I consume for each elements of an optional list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a List which can be null;

```
List<T> list; // may or may not null
```

I want to process for each element with a consumer.

So far, I do.

```
ofNullable(list)
        .map(List::stream)
        .ifPresent(stream -> stream.forEach(e -> {}));
```

or

```
ofNullable(eventDataList).ifPresent(v -> v.forEach(e -> {}));
```

Is there any easy or concise way to do this?

Comment: why not simply `if (list != null) { list.foreach(e->{});} ?` Functional programming style is cool but not necessary to be always cleaner and more readable.

Comment: @AdrianShum Because I've already known that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid ugly null checking, use orElse(Collections.emptyList())

```
Optional.ofNullable(eventDataList)
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .forEach(e -> {});
```

With static imports, it's pretty concise:

```
ofNullable(eventDataList).orElse(emptyList()).forEach(e -> {});
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, `if (list != null) { list.stream().forEach(e -> {...}); }` is both shorter and more efficient in terms of CPU/memory usage than your variants.

Architecturally, if you have control over initialization of the `list` and its usage, it's often better to use either `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `null` (if the logic of your program allows) or make the list `Optional` from the very beginning. That would save you from necessity to make checks or create `Optional`s every time you want to use the list.

Comment: I like that CPU/MEM concern. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you require to do something with every value in the list and say return a value then `ifPresent` will not work. Rather you can do something like below. In my example the optional list contains a user defined object `Person` which has a few attributes. I am iterating over the list and concatenating the values of a specific attribute and returning it.

```
public static class Person 
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(final String name, final int age)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
       return age;
    }
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        Person a = new Person("Alice", 1);
        Person b = new Person("Bob", 2);
        List<Person> personList = Lists.newArrayList(a, b);
        String concatNames = Optional.of(personList).map(people -> people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))).orElse(null);
        System.out.println("Names: "+concatNames);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can make it more concise. However, if you are frequently using the construct of looping over a nullable list and consuming each element, you could make a small class which does just that:

```
public class ListConsumer {
    public static <H> Consumer<List<H>> of(Consumer<H> consumer) {
        return hs -> hs.forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

You can then consume each element in a list as follows (e.g. print all Strings in list):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
Optional.ofNullable(list).ifPresent(ListConsumer.of(consumer));
```

Comment: I know this answer was given in 2016 before Java 9 so now, it can be handled using the native of() which would create an immutable list. I don't think it's good practice to allow an immutable list to be modified by adding elements to it.